# How to display dropdown values from nested arrays with KO

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array like this - NOTE "Options" array does not include[ ]; this is the data that is being returned by the server via MVC - originally I get this array like the commented code below:

```
//var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FieldList));):

var initialData = [{ "DisplayName": "Service Status",
"Options": { "123": "Active", "127": "Scrapped", "121": "Inactive" },
"Value": "123"
        }];
```

I want to put the values in Options into a dropdown with labels "Active", "Scrapped", "Inactive", each map to the respective numeric values listed in the array Options.

I want to have pre-selected on that dropdown the value "Active" that corresponds to 123.
The label for my dropdown will be "Service Status".

This is the code I have so far. But it only displays my Service Status dropdow with 1 element, Active. How can I add the other 2 elements to the dropdown?

If you can help me on this, I'll appreciate it very much.
Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;
    $(document).ready(function() {
           var initialData = [{ "DisplayName": "Service Status",
                  "Options": { "123": "Active", "127": "Scrapped", "121": "Inactive" },
                  "Value": "123"
           }];
        viewModel = { fields: ko.observableArray(initialData) };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>

<span data-bind="foreach: viewModel.fields">
<span data-bind="text:DisplayName"></span>
<select data-bind="options: Options,                                
                         optionsValue: Value"></select>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to map the object containing your value into an array that can work with the options binding.

Something like:

```
var optionsFromServer = data[0].Options,
    options = [];

for (var prop in optionsFromServer) {
    if (optionsFromServer.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        options.push({ id: prop, text: optionsFromServer[prop] });   
    }
}
```

Then, you can bind against this new options array like:

```
<select data-bind="options: options, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'text'"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am new into this. If you could help me more I'll appreciate it a lot.
If I understand what you suggest here, is that I must define labels for each of the items in Options, correct? For example in item ("123": "Active"), 'id' = 123 and 'text' = Active, correct? This way I can use those labels in the html and display them as needed.
I am new into this and I am not sure where I should define the code you posted here in my file. Could you help me a little more and/or guide me where to read/look to get more information on parsing nested arrays?

Comment: Also, be aware that for simplicity I only listed one item that contains Options; there are more items in the data (it is an array) that do not contain Options and have different fields to display. That is. saying [0] is not an option because I have to traverse an array.

Comment: Are the options on each item in the array different?

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing the basic idea with an array: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kJexT/

Comment: Yes, this is working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. I have lots to learn here.